# Diffrent validation message from javax @Pattern

Tags: java, validation

My class User has 2 fields with phones, one for mobile phone and second for work phone.

```
@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonView({View.Detail.class})
private Phone workPhone;

@Valid
@JsonView({View.Detail.class})
private Phone mobilePhone;
```

class Phone has field number validated by @Pattern

```
@JsonView({View.Country.class, View.Detail.class, View.Summary.class})
@NotBlank(message = "missing.phone")
@Pattern(regexp = Regexps.ONLY_DIGITS, message = ProfileMessages.MOBILE_PHONE_INVALID)
@Length(max = 25, message = CommonMessages.LENGTH_MAX)
private String number;
```

My problem is that message attribute of @Pattern is now profileMessages.MOBILE_PHONE_INVALID which is right only for mobile phone. Is there any way to dynamically change this message without for example creating new classes? When I tried adding new field and using it as message filler it shows me error that it should be constant value.

Comment: Why not validate inside the `User` class instead of `Phone`? BTW In annotations you can only use constants, there is no way to put a variable in there.

Comment: class Phone has other fields too